No. of ways to construct $k$ non-empty subsets from $n$-element multiset
I am trying to come up with a formula for the number of ways to create $k$ non-empty subsets from $n$ elements which are not necessarily distinct. For instance, let us say the numbers are $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots, a_{n}$, and the subsets are $l_{1},l_{2},\ldots,l_{k}$. Obviously the order of elements within a set does not matter.
Here is what I have done so far. Let us consider the $i$th element from the $n$ elements. If we were to allow for empty subsets also, then $a_{i}$ has $k$ options. Considering this option available across $a_{i}\forall 1\le i\le n$. We get $k^{n}$. From this we need to subtract the number of ways that we have where $j$ number of subsets remain empty, where $j$ ranges from $1$ to $(k-1)$. Let the number of ways be denoted by $\text{#}_{n,k}$. Essentially, we need to get a closed form expression for the following sum:
$$\text{#}_{n,k}=\displaystyle{\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^{k}|l_{i}|=n}}{n\choose |l_{i}|}, 1\le |l_{i}|\le\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\bigg\rfloor$$
So far I have been able to solve it for the case where $k=2$, where $\text{#}_{n,2}=2^{n-1}-1$. I am unable to generalise it for $k$. Any ideas/hints will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
If we think about it in terms of creating k partitions, which we can do by inserting (k-1) delimiters between n numbers, and since the order of numbers does not matter, we can shuffle the numbers to get all possible cases.
$$\text{#}_{n,k}=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i}|a_{i}|!}{n+1\choose k-1}$$
Am I thinking correctly. Any hints/ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: To paraphrase the original question, the $n$-elements could be considered as being elements of a multiset of size $n$.

Can you solve the question, when the $n$ elements are distinct?

@GerryMyerson In that case, it is modelled using Stirling numbers of the second kind.

If you extract from the list of $n$ elements the corresponding set of -say- $m$ (distinct) elements, then you know how to count the possibilities.  But, without further constraints on the initial list, I don't see how you can say anything more specific than that.

Please clarify your question. Apparently, you need to provide more data on the indistinguishable elements in order to even be able to work out the quantity that you are looking for. These data could be given in terms of a sequence $(u_k)$ where $u_k$ is the number of maximal subsets of your  $n$ items that have precisely $k$ non-distinguishable elements. Is this possibly what the $(a_i)$ are meant to be? If not, what is the meaning of the $(a_i)$?

Paras you may clarify everything by providing a small illustrative example  with all details of what you are looking for.
